# Using Google Client library in Android

Tags: android, google-api-client, android-googleapiclient

I've added some code that fetches a user profile information from the People Api after he signed in (using `GoogleSignInOptions`). This is the code:

```
private void getProfileData(final Context context, GoogleSignInAccount account, final ProfileDataListener listener) {
    ProfileDataTask profileDataTask = new ProfileDataTask(context, account, listener);
    profileDataTask.execute();
}

private static class ProfileDataTask extends AsyncTask<GoogleSignInAccount, Void, Person> {

    private GoogleAccountCredential credential;
    private String appName;
    private ProfileDataListener listener;

    ProfileDataTask(Context context, GoogleSignInAccount account, ProfileDataListener listener) {
        this.credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, Collections.singleton(Scopes.PROFILE));
        this.credential.setSelectedAccount(new Account(account.getEmail(), "com.google"));

        this.appName = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Person doInBackground(GoogleSignInAccount... accounts) {
        PeopleService service = new PeopleService.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
                .setApplicationName(appName)
                .build();
        try {
            return service.people()
                    .get("people/me")
                    .setPersonFields("genders,birthdays")
                    .execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Person person) {
        super.onPostExecute(person);

        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onCompleted(person);
        }
    }
}
```

This is very straight forward (eventhough the documentation for these apis are lacking) and everything works.

Gradle dependencies are:

```
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev299-1.23.0'
```

The problem is happening when im building in 'release' build type which uses proguard. My build is failing with the following:

> Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find superclass or interface javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
>   Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
>   Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
>   ... Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
>   Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category
>   Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category
>   Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
>   Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
>   Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority

when i run ./gradlew app:dependencies i see this:

[image]

It seems like google-api-client-android library depends on the more general google-api-client library which is not suited for android use. And subsequently contains non android components. Is this correct? How can i solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ok, finally found a solution.
I changed the Google Client API library gradle dependencies to this:

```
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    // Exclude artifacts that the Android SDK/Runtime provides.
    exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
    exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
    exclude(group: 'junit', module: 'junit')
    exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
}
implementation ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev299-1.23.0') {
    // Exclude artifacts that the Android SDK/Runtime provides.
    exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
    exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
    exclude(group: 'junit', module: 'junit')
    exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
}
```

Google documentation regarding the use of this library from android is terrible...